# Parsing text within caption tag in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm in the process of migrating a wordpress blog to Jekyll and ran into the following obstacle:

I would like to parse text such as

`[caption id="attachment_1749417" align="aligncenter" width="426"][![femur head cross section](http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/femur-head-cross-section.png)](http://www.bartleby.com/107/illus247.html) A cross-section of the top of the thigh bone. ![](http://www.wired.com/wp-content/themes/Phoenix/assets/images/gallery-cam@2x.png) [Gray's Anatomy](http://www.bartleby.com/107/illus247.html) / Public Domain[/caption]`

so that I recover all the text between the caption tags, i.e.

`[![femur head cross section](http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/femur-head-cross-section.png)](http://www.bartleby.com/107/illus247.html) A cross-section of the top of the thigh bone. ![](http://www.wired.com/wp-content/themes/Phoenix/assets/images/gallery-cam@2x.png) [Gray's Anatomy](http://www.bartleby.com/107/illus247.html) / Public Domain`

I tried the following Python code:

```
match = re.search("\[caption.*\](.*)\[\/caption\]",caption)
if match and len(match.groups()) > 0:
    actualcaption = match.groups()[0]
    print 'actual caption: '+ actualcaption
```

However that only gives me `(http://www.bartleby.com/107/illus247.html) / Public Domain`

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issues are that

- you are accessing `match.groups()[0]` while you should access `match.group(1)` because you *capture* the part you need with the pair of unescaped parentheses in the pattern and they are the only pair of capturing parentheses, thus having ID = 1.
- you are using greedy quantifiers with `.*`, while you need `.*?` to match as few chars other than line breaks as possible

NOTE: if the text spans across multiple lines, you also should pass `re.DOTALL` or `re.S` to [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) so that `.` could match line break chars.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CQhtz1/1) and a [Python demo](http://ideone.com/27nOQd):

```
import re
regex = r"\[caption.*?](.*?)\[/caption]"
test_str = "[caption id=\"attachment_1749417\" align=\"aligncenter\" width=\"426\"][![femur head cross section](http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/femur-head-cross-section.png)](http://www.bartleby.com/107/illus247.html) A cross-section of the top of the thigh bone. ![](http://www.wired.com/wp-content/themes/Phoenix/assets/images/gallery-cam@2x.png) [Gray's Anatomy](http://www.bartleby.com/107/illus247.html) / Public Domain[/caption]"
match = re.search(regex, test_str)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

that prints:

```
[![femur head cross section](http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/femur-head-cross-section.png)](http://www.bartleby.com/107/illus247.html) A cross-section of the top of the thigh bone. ![](http://www.wired.com/wp-content/themes/Phoenix/assets/images/gallery-cam@2x.png) [Gray's Anatomy](http://www.bartleby.com/107/illus247.html) / Public Domain
```